# Pandas: Cant Insert Pivot Table information into a different Sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pivot-table, pandas.excelwriter

I have a code where I convert a txt to xlsx, then add a column with formulas and then I want to create a Pivot Table with that information in a different Sheet. The code works without errors but it creates and empty Sheet instead of a Sheet with information.

So the code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import openpyxl

#Transforming our txt to xlsx
path = r"C:\Users\roslber\Desktop\Codes\Python\Projects\Automated routes.xlsx"
rssdata= pd.read_csv("dwp.txt", sep="\t")
rssdata.to_excel(path, index= None , header= True)                        

#Writing the formula column
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=path)
ws1 = wb["Sheet1"]  
ws1["AC1"] = "CF Weight"                                                      
row_count= ws1.max_row
actual_row= 2
while actual_row <= row_count:                                        #writting the formula in every row
    r= str(actual_row)
    ws1["AC"+r] = "=(O"+r + "*P"+r +"*Q"+r +")/28316.8"
    actual_row= actual_row + 1

#Creating a new sheet with the pivot tables  
df = pd.read_excel(path, 0, header= 0)                                      #defining pivot table dataframe
wb.create_sheet("Sheet2")
 
pv_pack = pd.pivot_table(df, values=["actual_service_time"],\
index=["delivery_station_code"], columns=["cluster_prefix"], aggfunc=np.sum)  #constructing the pivot table

print(pv_pack)

with pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode="a") as writer:
    pv_pack.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet2") 
    writer.save()                                                      #inserting pivot table in sheet2

wb.save(path)
```

For data protection reasons I can´t show you the information inside the pivot table but when I print it I can see exactly what I want. The problem is that, although a Sheet2 is created correctly, The information that I can see printed doesn't appear in Sheet2. Why is this happening?

I have checked these questions:

1. [Trouble writing pivot table to excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529632/trouble-writing-pivot-table-to-excel-file)
2. [How to save a new sheet in an existing excel file, using Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370977/how-to-save-a-new-sheet-in-an-existing-excel-file-using-pandas)

Regarding to the first one, apparently openpyxl can't create a Pivot Table, but I actually don't need a Pivot Table format, I just need the pv_pack information in Sheet2 as its shown when I print it.

I tried to change my code to imitate what they did in the second question but it didn't work.

Thank you in advance

**Edit answering to RJ Adriaansen**:
The information in Sheet1 would look like this:

```
id  order   mtd delivery_station_code   cluster_prefix   actual_service_time
xh  aabb1   one     1                    One_            231    
xr  aabb2   two     2                    Two_            135    
xd  aabb3   three   3                    One_            80 
xh  aabb8   two     1                    Two_            205    
xp  aabb9   three   2                    One_            1  
xl  aabb10  one     3                    Two_            115
```

And the code printed in my editor looks like this:

```
delivery_station_code One_  Two_
1                     231   205
2                     1     135
3                     80    115
```

Comment: Can you post some fictitious dummy data that mimics your text file so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I just have added some dummy data to the question

Comment: Please post the dummy data as text in stead of an image

Comment: I have just posted it as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`with` automatically closes the file, so there is no need to try to save it manually. It is also not needed to create the second sheet prior to writing it. Removing `writer.save()` and moving `wb.save(path)` up will make the code work.

```
#Writing the formula column
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=path)
ws1 = wb["Sheet1"]  
ws1["AC1"] = "CF Weight"                                                      
row_count= ws1.max_row
actual_row= 2

while actual_row <= row_count:                                        #writting the formula in every row
    r= str(actual_row)
    ws1["AC"+r] = "=(O"+r + "*P"+r +"*Q"+r +")/28316.8"
    actual_row= actual_row + 1
wb.save(path)

#Creating a new sheet with the pivot tables  
df = pd.read_excel(path, 0, header= 0)                                      #defining pivot table dataframe
 
pv_pack = pd.pivot_table(df, values=["actual_service_time"],\
index=["delivery_station_code"], columns=["cluster_prefix"], aggfunc=np.sum)  #constructing the pivot table

with pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode="a") as writer:
    pv_pack.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet2")
```

Comment: Awesome Adriaansen. That's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much